# Conjugacy class enough to make it Abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am asked to prove:

**Any group containing only second order elements and identity is Abelian.**

Is it enough to say that because each element is a conjugacy class by itself, then the group has to be Abelian?

Thanks.

Comment: I mean conjugacy class.

Comment: One usually says ***elements of order $2$***.

Comment: if  every element of order 2 then $a^2=e$ then $a=a^{-1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(ab)^2=e=a^2b^2$ for all $a,b\in G$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x,y\not=e$ and $x\not=y^{-1}.$ Then $$xy=x^{-1}y^{-1}=(yx)^{-1}=yx.$$